Is "Can I install any of Google's apps on an Apple Silicon (arm64/M1) Mac? Which ones and how?" a practical problem/valid question?
Is "Can I install any of these Google apps (that's a link to all the ones in Apple's App Store) on an Apple Silicon (arm64/M1) Mac? Which ones and how?" a practical problem/valid question forth?  I asked the meta question [twice][1], but got no answer. I think a lot of people want to install them and are confused when they can't find Google apps in the Mac App Store, and would like to help them. That was me.
[1]: In comments at A lot of people wonder why they can't find google apps in the Mac App Store. I did, and so I created a Q&A for it. Baffled by resulting hostility

Your question likely lacked focus and was basically an attempt to use AD as a Wiki, which it is not.
If you are having an issue with one or more of those apps, great! We can help. But @Nohillside’s answer was succinct and and to the point and entirely delivered with ZERO hostility and said it best why the question was closed.
AD is strictly a place to find solutions to specific, clearly defined, problems. And besides, who says that people wonder why they can’t find google apps on the App Store? I was able to find them no problem, and if it won’t work on your device (iPhone, Mac, etc.) the App Store won’t let you download it or at the least give you a compatibility warning.
We are always happy to help you with specific troubleshooting issues. But that was not a troubleshooting issue.

Really?  "I was able to find them no problem"?  Where is and how do I install the Gmail app on my Mac?

It doesn't exist.  Anyway, I asked a NEW question, which @Nohillside did NOT answer, succintly or otherwise. "Is "Can I install any of Google's apps on an Apple Silicon (arm64/M1) Mac? Which ones and how?" a practical problem/valid question?"

That lacks focus, if you ask about one particular app and detail the issues you are having with it, that would do well. Also AD is not designed as a wiki, and attempts to turn it into one are usually shut down by the mods.
